# Nominal sentence (sentence without verb)

Tags: sentence-structure

Short question. Is 'I happy' correct? you mad, I happy.

Comment: No. A 'sentence' like that would only be used when imitating the speech of a person with very limited English..

Comment: Short answer: no. Slightly longer answer: in some forms of pidgin English, these do occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not correct, except as a slang or idomatic expression. "Me Tarzan, you Jane" was a famous line from the movie, said by a man raised in the jungle who spoke broken English.

The correct form must have a verb: You are mad. I am happy.